# Windows kivy app successfully builds using PyInstaller, but doesn't work

Tags: python, windows, kivy, pyinstaller

I tried to create an executable file in Windows from a `kivy` project with `PyInstaller`, and even though it appears to have been successfully created, when I try to run it, I get this

[image: error]

What could cause this? I'm relatively new to `kivy`, and any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I actually figured it out myself. Though I don't think that my solution is in any way elegant and it might cause some other problems in the future, but i just edited the pyi_rth_pkgutil.py from PyInstaller package directory ([how it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmVyl.png),  [how it used to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns1Lf.png)) and reran the pyinstaller package creation script. It just worked after that