# I cant run py python kivy app after i build the exe file

Tags: python, kivy

I tested my app in vs code and ran my app fine . but when I export this app :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "kivy\__init__.py", line 272, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\0123m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py", line 71, in _pyi_pkgutil_iter_modules
    assert pkg_path.startswith(SYS_PREFIX)
TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not PureWindowsPath
```

I exported this using the command that kivy provided

Comment: Does this solve your question? [Windows kivy app successfully builds using PyInstaller, but doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68373216/9997212)

Comment: The last error line is fixed. but still, the program not running.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "kivy\__init__.py", line 297, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'load_module'


```